# How to combine Appbar with BottomNavigation from React Native Paper?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-paper

The **BottomNavigation** is a great navigator for mobile devices but for web version I would prefer to have a something as below (inspired by Instagram):

[image: Screenshot]

**Navbar.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Appbar, BottomNavigation} from 'react-native-paper'

type NavbarProps = React.ComponentProps<typeof Appbar> &
  React.ComponentProps<typeof BottomNavigation>

export const Navbar: React.FC<NavbarProps> = (props: NavbarProps) => {
  return (
    <Appbar {...props}>
      {props.children}
      <BottomNavigation {...props} />
    </Appbar>
  )
}
```

**Example of usage:**

```
const App = () => {
  const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme()
  const isDarkTheme = colorScheme === 'dark'
  const theme = isDarkTheme ? CombinedDarkTheme : CombinedDefaultTheme

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = React.useState('')
  const onChangeSearch = (query: React.SetStateAction<string>) => {
    setSearchQuery(query)
  }

  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    {key: 'home', icon: 'home'},
    {key: 'map', icon: 'compass'},
    {key: 'post', icon: 'plus-box'},
    {key: 'chat', icon: 'forum'},
    {key: 'profile', icon: 'account'},
  ])

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    home: HomeScreen,
    map: MapScreen,
    post: PostScreen,
    chat: ChatScreen,
    profile: ProfileScreen,
  })

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <React.Fragment>
        <style type="text/css">{`
          @font-face {
            font-family: 'MaterialCommunityIcons';
            src: url('fonts/MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf') format('truetype');
          }
        `}</style>
        <Navbar
          style={styles.navbar}
          labeled={false}
          navigationState={{index, routes}}
          onIndexChange={setIndex}
          renderScene={renderScene}
          activeColor="#f50057">
          <Navbar.Content title="My cool navbar" />
          <Navbar.Search
            theme={theme}
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={searchQuery}
            onChangeText={onChangeSearch}
          />
        </Navbar>
      </React.Fragment>
    </PaperProvider>
  )
}
```

This code gives me the bar that I need but it doesn't render a scene. To be more precise, it draws the scene, but inside the Appbar and with zero height, which is logical.

[image: Screenshot 2]

If to look at [source code](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/main/src/components/BottomNavigation/BottomNavigation.tsx) of **BottomNavigation**, it renders **BottomNavigationRouteScreen** and below its bar with icons.

How can I extend **BottomNavigation** to add the title and search (just some nested views) at the beginning of the bar from **BottomNavigation** and render **BottomNavigationRouteScreen** below the bar?

**P.S.** I didn't post a code related to **Navbar.Content** and **Navbar.Search** because of it doesn't play any role in my problem.
**P.P.S.** I am a noobie in **React.js** and **React Native**.

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts to implement **Navbar** in my app, I've realised there is much easier way. I forked [React Native Paper repository](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper) and implemented **Navbar** in their library directly: [here](https://github.com/Klein-Stein/react-native-paper/compare/v4.11.2...v4.11.5-internal).
This **Navbar** is based on **BottomNavigation** source code and I can't call this solution perfect but it works for my app. There is a smarter way to redesign a built-in **Appbar**, introduce new **Toolbar** and **TabBar** as it was made in Android native components. It would make **Appbar** much more flexible for setting.